# Nested Rows inside table with shared headers - Aura Iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration

I'm trying to create a table with nested rows based on nested array data set with following structure:

[ 
  'key1' : [
             'subKey1' : 'subValue1',
             'subKey2' : 'subValue2',
           ],
  'key2' : [
             'subKey1' : 'subValue1'
           ]
]

I'd like the table to display with shared headings and first column height should span length of inner array for that row. For example:

[image]

Instead, I get the following:
[image]

My code for this is below:

```
            <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
            <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-title--caps slds-cell-wrap">
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap" title="A">A</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap" title="B">B</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap" title="C">C</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap" title="D">D
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap" title="E">E</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap" title="F">F</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap" title="G">G</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate slds-cell-wrap" title="H">H</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.data}" var="row" indexVar="key">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" data-label="A" rowspan="{!row.value.length}">
                        parent{!key+1}
                    </th>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!row.value}" var="subRow" indexVar="num">
                        <th>b{!num+1}</th>
                        <th>c{!num+1}</th>
                        <th>d{!num+1}</th>
                        <th>e{!num+1}</th>
                        <th>f{!num+1}</th>
                        <th>g{!num+1}</th>
                        <th>h{!num+1}</th>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I've tried putting another "tr" element inside the inner iteration but that just lumps everything under one heading. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try  `lightning:treegrid` https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:treeGrid/example

Comment: I have used tree grid previously but I need some unescaped html in some of the cells and wasn't sure if that was possible with treegrid. Looking for a vanilla html implementation of possible